# Failed to build an iOS app in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, swift

My app is written in swift, and it works pretty well in the simulator. However, when I try to build it for my iPad, it says

```
"Cannot load underlying module for 'Foundation"
"Cannot load underlying module for 'Foundation"
"Cannot load underlying module for 'Foundation"
"Cannot load underlying module for 'Foundation"
```

The iPad is in iOS 8, and the project is targeted for iOS 8

Comment: Is your iPad iOS 8? Is your project targeted for iOS 8? You need to provide a lot more details.

Comment: I started getting this error too today. My specs are. iPhone 5, running iOS8 Beta 3. Xcode Beta 3. XCode deployment target is 7.1. Runs fine in simulator, compile errors trying to run on device.

Comment: Not a real solution, but I fixed it by reinstalling XCode 6.0 Beta3. Ran a clean and everything works again.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check `Foundation.framework` in your SDK for device targets:

`ls /Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks | grep ^Foundation`.

It must exists, if not, reinstallation of Xcode will fix this problem.

(Note: SDK frameworks for device and simulator are located in other folders)

Answer (score 1):

If Xcode 6.1 starts messing around like that, easy fix is to delete user settings by removing Xcode folder: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode.

Backup your keybindings and themes first from ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the issue navigator, XCode will let you know the path it looked for Foundation in. Part of the path will include what Platform it's looking for.

In my case, I updated to XCode 6 Beta 3 and had this error caused by the deployment target defaulting to OSX 10.10 which I don't have installed.

You can click your project name to change your deployment target.

In my case, changing the deployment target back to 10.9 fixed this.